# Use with autoclose in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In stdlib/ kotlin.io we find

```
inline fun <T : Closeable?, R> T.use(block: (T) -> R): R (source)
```

However it is implemented on Closeable and not on the superinterface AutoCloseable. When working with some frameworks that use AutoCloseable this can be a bit painfull.

Why doesn't Kotlin support "use" with AutoCloseble ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `kotlin-stdlib` is meant for usage with JDK 6 and above, so that it is not aware of `AutoCloseable` (only added in Java 7).

But you can find the function you need in [`kotlin-stdlib-jre7`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.1.0), the stdlib extension for JDK 7 added for Kotlin 1.1. You can replace the `kotlin-stdlib` dependency with it since it depends on the base stdlib itself.

It is defined as:

```
public inline fun <T : AutoCloseable?, R> T.use(block: (T) -> R): R { ... }
```

<sup>[(api reference)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/use.html) [(github source)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jre7/src/kotlin/AutoCloseable.kt#L33)</sup>

And it was first mentioned in [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/07/first-glimpse-of-kotlin-1-1-coroutines-type-aliases-and-more/).

Comment: I get deprecation warnings now for the `JRE` version, but the `JDK` version seems to be missing Autocloseable.use, is there a reason? (both were Kotlin `1.2.21`)